# How to make already uploaded configset trusted after enabling auth in solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr8

Currently I am using solr 7 in cloud mode and security is not enable. I already have many collection in this solr cluster and configset already already uploaded which are currently untrusted.

Now I am upgrading my solr cluster to latest version which is 8.11. As per the document all configset uploaded without authentication are untrusted and we can not use them to collection creation and to make them trusted we have to enable the authentication and upload those configset with authentication.

Now I have to enable the basic authentication.

My question is how can I make already uploaded configset trusted so that I can use them to create more collection.